# A way to reduce the number of manually created DTOs

Tags: c#, json

I'm fairly new to services based architecture, so kindly bare that in mind when responding. The project I'm working on has a lot of potential data objects that need mapping to server-side representation of these objects. All service methods return them with JSON notation. I've created DTOs to handle the mapping from JSON objects to server-side objects. However, I'm finding too much duplication amongst my DTOs. For instance...

I have many JSON objects that have this simple structure:

`[ 
    { "gender": "male" }, 
    { "gender": "female" }
 ]`

My corresponding DTO would look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Gender
{
    [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
    public string GenderValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have 15 more JSON objects with the same structure, namely, a one field object with a string value. Rather than creating 15 DTOs, I'd like a method with parameters like field name and field type that would dynamically create a DTO , but I'm not confident that's the best solution.

Suggestions?

Comment: What you have is an array, [an ordered list of zero or more values, each of which may be of any type. Arrays use square bracket notation with elements being comma-separated.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Comment: You are sending or receiving those objects?

Comment: DTO can serve the purpose of presenting data differently than its original form (without changing the original types obviously), inherently it's a lot of boiler-plate code. To help you in such matter you can use something like https://automapper.codeplex.com/. For instance, you can create interfaces of your original objects and generate DTOs from these interfaces; something like Resharper will implement them with a mouse click. Finally, AutoMapper will map the values with little intervention from you.

Comment: Thanks Aybe. That's helpful information. Unfortunately, ReSharper isn't an option, but I'll check out automapper.

Comment: @usr, I am receiving these objects.